# What is the fastest way to randomise a 4 digit value with values from (0,9)? Lets debate

Tags: python

Good afternoon,

I am curios to find out how to generate a four digit number with values from 0 to 9 in the ***fastest way possible***.

I have a program that takes in a four digit values and then have to generate the exact same number. So a value is known and to program tries to guess what the value is.

Should i approach this by comparing lists? like so:

```
guess = [randint(0, 9) for p in range(0, 4)]
```

or by looping i until the value is found

```
for i in range(0, 9999)
```

By doing the for loop example I can not generate a value like "0001" for example...

this is the program so far:

```
def guessDigits():

    guess = np.random.randint(0, 9999)

return guess

if __name__ == '__main__':

    start = time.time()
    i = 0
    for i in range(100):

        value = guessDigits() #new 4 digit value is genrated
        guess = guessDigits() #first guess

        while guess != value:
            guess = guessDigits() #guess again
            i = i + 1

    end = time.time()

    tot = (end - start)/100 #mean value for every guess

    print("your value is: ", guess)
    print("time: ", tot)
    print("index: ", i )
```

***This seems to be faster:***

```
    def guessDigits():
        guess = np.random.randint(0, 9999)
        return guess

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        start = time.time()

        i = 0
        for i in range(100):

            guess = guessDigits() #new value

            for i in range(9999):
                i = i + 1

                if i == guess:

                    print(i)
                    break
```

What do you think is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your second approach? It doesn't seem to be using `random` at all, so I don't think it's very random.

Comment: updated the description :)

Comment: If you have to get a number that's equal to another number, then the fastest way is `new_number = other_number`. If you're thinking "no, no, I have to generate it randomly", then you can't do `for i in range(0, 9999):`, because that's not random. If you're thinking "I don't have to generate it randomly, but I do have to generate it, and `new_number = other_number` isn't generation", then you will have to explain further what "generation" is, because outside of the context of random number generation, that word doesn't have a specific meaning.

Comment: added the code for the program. My friend is going through a for loop comparing "i" for every step. And that solution seems to be faster. in other words, he doest randomise the guess for every guess he just goes through the loop comparing "i" too the value.

Comment: If your question is "is it faster to match a number by iterating over all numbers in a range, or by generating random numbers in that range?", then they're about the same in the average case, but if you're very very unlucky, then the random generation strategy might _never_ find the correct value. Theoretically, there's nothing stopping a random number generator from generating "9999" over and over for a hundred million years. (most PRNGs won't do this, but if anything that's a fault that makes them a poor approximation of true random generation)

Comment: ahaa I see! So if i have to compare o lot of values I should not randomise the guesses

Answer (score 3):

Use just `np.random.randint` as it is the fastest. using a list comprehension *will* be slow as python list are not known to be fast:

```
%%timeit
from random import randint
guess = [randint(0, 9) for p in range(0, 4)]
>>> 100000 loops, best of 3: 12.4 µs per loop

%%timeit
from random import randint
guess = randint(0, 9999)
>>> 100000 loops, best of 3: 4.33 µs per loop

%%timeit
guess = np.random.randint(0, 9999)
>>> 100000 loops, best of 3: 2.54 µs per loop
```

Comment: Numpy usually takes quite a while to import on my machine... For that reason, I'd only use it to generate random numbers if I had already imported numpy for some other purpose. Importing it only so I could use randint would only be sensible if I was generating millions of numbers.

Comment: @Kevin Well, if generating number's time became a concern I would imagine you're going to be generating millions of it.